# How to remove the top horizontal bar in fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer, rules, fancyhdr

When using `fancyhdr`, how do you remove the top horizontal rule? 
I do not want a header at all, just a footer.

This is what I do now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lfoot{text}
\cfoot{text 2}
\rfoot{text 3}

\begin{document}
Foo Bar
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 240):

There are various examples in the `fancyhdr` documentation of redefining the `\headrulewidth`:

```
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% your new footer definitions here
```

will do what you want.

To learn more about `fancyhdr`, you could either look into [its documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fancyhdr) or at the [respective chapter in the Wikibook LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Customizing_with_fancyhdr).

Comment: I added a couple of resources from an answer I was going to give on a duplicate of this question, hope that's okay.

Comment: I realize this question is quite old now, and this isn't exactly on topic, but I have a question regarding the use of `\renewcommand`.  Is there any difference between what you wrote and `\setlength{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`?

Comment: @JonathanGleason Yes, there is a difference.  `fancyhdr` implements these lengths as macros and not actual lengths, so `\setlength` simply won't work for them.  Macros don't consume any of TeX's length registers, which is part of the motivation that the `fancyhdr` author gives for this implementation. It is, however, a bit unintuitive and non-standard. Generally lengths *would* be set using `\setlength` but in this case they are not actually lengths in the underlying coding.

Comment: For completeness: \footrulewidth is the other macro. I hope to save someone else's time ;-)