# How to remove header bar in fancyhdr's \pagestyle{fancy}

Tags: header-footer, rules, fancyhdr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the top horizontal bar in fancyhdr?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13896/how-to-remove-the-top-horizontal-bar-in-fancyhdr)

I am working on my report and found one example.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,LO]{MY TEXT}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
Foo Bar
\end{document}
```

This adds footer and header both. But I need only a footer, no header. How can I add footer only (no bar in header)?

Comment: I reworked your question a bit, with a more specific title and a complete code example. However, I just noticed it's been asked here before, so this one will be closed. Please always thoroughly search the existing questions before asking a new one!