# Page numbering in header/footer (fancyhdr)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the top horizontal bar in fancyhdr?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13896/how-to-remove-the-top-horizontal-bar-in-fancyhdr)

How would I get rid of the line in the header, and the line and page numbering in the footer?

My code is below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, lipsum, bibentry,fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{My Name}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}



\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}\bfseries\Huge John Doe \end{center}
\vspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.70\textwidth}
Address Line 1\\
Address Line 2\\
Address Line 3\\
Address Line 4\\
Address Line 5
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Mobile: 123-456789\\
Email: myemail@gmail.com\\
Date of Birth: 01/01/2012\\
Citizenship: My citizenship
\end{minipage}
\vspace{2pt}

\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008--2012&MSc in Computer Science, Great University, Country.\vspace{5pt}\\
2006--2008&BSc in Life Science, Great University, Country.\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Professional Experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2011--today&{\bf Work at company XY.}Head of Department. Add my job description here. Add my job description here. Add my job description here. Add my job description here.\\
&\begin{itemize}
\item Add my job description here.
\item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
\item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
\item Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.Add my job description here.
\end{itemize} \vspace{5pt}\\
2008--2010&{\bf Trainee at company ZY.}\\
&\lipsum[66]\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Awards and Achievements}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008&Gold medal.\vspace{5pt}\\
2006&Silver medal.\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Organisational Experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2008&This event.\vspace{5pt}\\
\end{tabular}


\section*{Languages}
English, Spanish, French, German


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please have a look at the `fancyhdr` maual and at the various questions tagged with [tag:fancyhdr], e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13896/how-to-remove-the-top-horizontal-bar-in-fancyhdr

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From your MWE just few changes:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{My Name}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{} % get rid of the page number 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

By setting the `\headrulewidth` and `\footrulewidth` to `0pt` you can remove them as described in the documentation of the package [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/).

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Sorry, might have missed out reading that part in the documention.