# Remove line from Header

Tags: header-footer, rules, fancyhdr

I am using

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
........
\lhead{My Name}
```

This setup creates header with a horizontal line.

1. How can I remove line appearing in header?
2. When I convert this document to pdf it creates one inch extra space in my header. This space does not show up in dvi display or in postscript file. But does show up in pdf. How can I remove extra space in pdf?

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage {amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools, fancyhdr}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 

\usepackage[margin=0.7in, headsep=4pt]{geometry} 

\begin{document}
\chead{My Name, Date...... }

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{lcr}
e^{-at} \hspace{1cm} \sin bt & \frac{b}{(s+a)^2+b^2} \hspace{1cm} & s>-a\\
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) For your first question see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13896/how-to-remove-the-top-horizontal-bar-in-fancyhdr. For the second question please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Are you using US Letter paper or ISO A4 paper?

Comment: Your document seems to work fine for me.  Try using `\usepackage{showframe}`.  My guess is that it's your viewer.  Some viewers add extra space around the edges of your document.  There should be a setting to turn such behavior off.  By using `showframe`, you'll better be able to judge whether it's something with LaTeX or something with your viewer.

Comment: Also, the order you're calling things doesn't seem correct.  You should invoke the `geometry` package before you use `fancyhdr`.  Otherwise, `fancyhdr` won't get the margins correct.  Also, if you're going to use the `geometry` package, I'm not sure why you're setting `\evensidemargin` and `\rightsidemargin`.  I believe that the `geometry` package overrides your setting.

Answer (score 15):

You can set the width of the rules using

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

That should effectively make them disappear.

Comment: what about second problem? extra space in pdf.

Comment: The second problem sounds like something going on with your viewer.  But, it might help if you posted a MWE for which others can recreate the same problem.

Comment: Here is my example that creates an extra space at the beginning of the document while viewing pdf file.

Comment: how to make it readable? All lines are combined together. Check my original post.

Comment: This did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the solution to the second problem, you should remove the `headsep=4pt` from the `geometry` package settings or reduce its value. That removes or reduces the space between the header and the top edge of the page.

I am not sure why you are using `headsep` in `geometry` package if you don't want extra spaces in header.