# Removing the page number at the bottom of the page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I'm making a report in latex, using the report documentclass, and i want to remove the page numbers on the buttom of the pages, that latex automatically adds, while also having the page number in the header instead. Can anybody help?

edit: I am using fancyhdr. My question has been answered, thank you guys.

Comment: maybe the `fancyhdr` package is useful? (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr?lang=en)

Comment: I am using fanyhdr, but how to make it remove the number on the buttom, while still being capable of showing it in the header?

Comment: Please provide short, complete document (minimal working example), which we can compile. In it show how you use `fancyhdr`. With this your document we will can more easy to help you. Also try to search for similar question here. They are quite often.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Load this in your preamble

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
```

A good description for the start is given in [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Headers_and_footers). The `fancyhdr` package provides a lot of flexibility. You could also have a look at the `koma-script` classes.

Comment: If you want to remove the page number at the bottom without adding anything to the top, these two commands work.  `\fancyhf{}` `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` 
 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13896/how-to-remove-the-top-horizontal-bar-in-fancyhdr#13897

Answer (score 1):

Just issue the instruction

```
\pagestyle{myheadings}
```

(The default is `\pagestyle{plain}`.)

Note that you'll still page numbers placed at the bottom of the page for pages with chapter-level headings. This is usually a good idea since you wouldn't want page-number information competing visually with chapter-number information.

If you want any chapter-related information to be shown in the header line alongside the page numbers, use the `headings` page style, rather than the `myheadings` style.