# removing horizontal bar from fancyhdr header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

The following codegenerates a header with an horizontal. How can I get rid of it? Thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,hidelinks,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{My Header}
```

Note this question is different from
[How to remove the top horizontal bar in fancyhdr?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13896/how-to-remove-the-top-horizontal-bar-in-fancyhdr)
where the title is misleding, as the author did not want headers at all.

Comment: \setlength{\headrulewidth}{0pt} (untested, from memory)

Comment: Have a look in the good manual (`fancyhdr.pdf`), e. g. page 7 and 8: " Also allowed are changes to `\headrulewidth` and
`\footrulewidth`." and  "The following settings are used for the decorative lines: `\headrulewidth 0.4pt`" It's most of the times a good idea to have a look at the manual before asking.

Comment: @Johannes_B In the manual the syntax `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}` is used.

Comment: I saw that one. But then noticed the question said "do not want a header at all", and the solution was using ‘\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing’