# How I can delete the line at top of page , and apply this work to all pages of my document

Tags: header-footer

```
\documentclass[12pt]{thesis}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

My text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related/possible duplicate? [How to remove the top horizontal bar in fancyhdr?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13896/134144)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the top horizontal bar in fancyhdr?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13896/how-to-remove-the-top-horizontal-bar-in-fancyhdr)