# Remove header line in Latex

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, rules

I want to remove the header, but I am not sure how to do this. I cannot remove the line in the header. This is the code I am using:

```
\usepackage{sectsty,fancyhdr}
\sectionfont{\LARGE\bfseries}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5764

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{Project tile}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt} 
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\lfoot{\leftmark}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\z@
      \thesection\hskip 1em\relax
    \fi #1}{}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`

Comment: See also [How to remove the top horizontal bar in fancyhdr?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13896/134144)

Comment: @Neri did the answer help or meet your requirement

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{sectsty,fancyhdr}
\sectionfont{\LARGE\bfseries}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5764

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{}%<-----------------------------------------change
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%<---------------change
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt} 
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\lfoot{\leftmark}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\z@
      \thesection\hskip 1em\relax
    \fi #1}{}}
\makeatother
```